# Drupal node_form undefined function

Tags: php, api, drupal, drupal-7

When I run [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) in my module I get the following error: *Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_form()*

Is there some special context required to use this function, because I can't work out why it would be undefined when the API reference says that it's defined in modules/node/node.pages.inc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular file is not included by default so you need to do it manually:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drupal_get_form` instead of `node_form`.

Comment: Without including the file there will still be an error, it will just be different.

Comment: pass the `nodeid` in node object.